# sqlite3 bindings in regex

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to search a SQLite database in Python based on the simple regex %value%. However, when trying to use a binding to prevent SQL Injection, sqlite3 doesn't recognize ? as a binding when surrounded in percentage symbols. How can I get sqlite3 to recognize my binding while being used in a regular expression?

```sql
SELECT * FROM opportunities WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE LOWER('%?%');
```

run with

```py
print(sql, values)
cursor.execute(sql, ('somequery',))
```

returns

```
SELECT * FROM opportunities WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE LOWER('%?%'); ('somequery',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[REDACTED]", line 86, in <module>
    opportunitiesSearchResults = databaseFunctions.searchOpportunities(memCursor, currentFilter)
  File "[REDACTED]", line 102, in searchOpportunities
    cursor.execute(sql, values)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Comment: There’s no regex in your query. SQL’s LIKE is a pattern-matching predicate, similar to simple shell pattern matches.  (SQL’s SIMILAR, however, _is_ a regular expression predicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` is not a placeholder when it's quoted. You need to take it out of the quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM opportunities WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE '%' || LOWER(?) || '%'
```